# Items hover-event doesn't work when mouse is dragging other item

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a QGraphicsView with two kinds of items sub-classed from QGraphicsItem. The first kind of items (A) is moveable. The second kind (B) should always highlight when it is under the mouse-pointer.

If B is under A, B can still highlight. But if the mouse-pointer is over B while A is being dragged B won't highlight.

What would be the cleanest way to enable this behavior?

**EDIT**

this is how I implemented highlighting for B:

```
def hoverEnterEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.hover = True
    self.update()

def hoverLeaveEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.hover = False
    self.update()

def paint(self, painter, *args, **kwargs):
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    if self.hasFocus() or self.hover:
        painter.setPen(self.pen_selected)
    else:
        painter.setPen(self.pen())
    painter.drawPath(self.path())
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are highlighting item B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending a Signal from A's `mouseMoveEvent` and set a hover Attribute in B from the `QGraphicsScene`.

It works, but is not the most elegant solution. If someone has a better approach please post it and I will change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing to highlight item B, do that in B's `dragEnterEvent` too, so that the B becomes highlighted when some other item is being dragged over it.

Comment: That only works if A starts a `QDrag`. If I do that A no longer moves with the cursor, so I just set the `ItemIsMovable` flag without tapping into the drag and drop system.